# Bootstrap brand logo between links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, response, navbar

Need help with this problem, how to insert brand logo between navigation links? And how to move link near the brand logo like this [image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqsZJ.jpg). And I need responsive to works great. [Here is code.](https://jsfiddle.net/phg350de/)

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-brand-centered">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered">Logo</div>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-brand-centered">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Use grid columns for the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-brand-centered">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-brand-centered">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered">Logo</div>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Change bootstrap CSS:

```
.navbar-nav > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-inner {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks 
https://jsfiddle.net/phg350de/4/

HTML:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-brand-centered">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered">Logo</div>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-brand-centered">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        </div>
      </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-brand-centered {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
display: block;
width: 180px;
text-align: center;
background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar>.container .navbar-brand-centered,
.navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand-centered {
margin-left: -80px;
}
```